# how to reset event subscription on scene reset (reload)

Tags: unity-game-engine, event-handling

I have a scene that I would like to reload when a player fails. I do this with `SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");` but then I have this error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'AudioSource' has been
>   destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

After some digging I found that the problem is caused by me events. It looks like the subscribers from previous scene are still active and are looking for objects tat are already destroyed. So questions are:

1. Is it possible to somehow clear all subscribers or do I have to unsubscribe them one by one before loading new scene?
2. (I know that I shouln't ask that but...) Can you point me to some tutorial or example of simple event manager? I am thinking about some static class that will wrap my eventhandlers and allow me to manage subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**.It is possible to clear all the subscribers but it is better to unsubscribe in each script you subscribed in. This is not hard. **Unsubscribe** in the `OnDisable()` function in every class you subscribed to an event and you won't be having the problem you are currently having.

**CLEAR INDIVIDUAL EVENT**:

```
void OnDisable(){
ClassName.eventName -= functionName;
}
```

**CLEAR ALL EVENTS**:

If the event is `Unity UI Event` you can use `RemoveAllListeners()` to remove all subscribers.

Assuming you are using C# `event` and `delegates`, and the name of you **delegate** is `buttonPressed` while the name of your **event** is `onButtonPressed`, you can remove a subscribers by doing

```
    if (onButtonPressed != null)
    {
        System.Delegate[] deletegates = onButtonPressed.GetInvocationList();
        for (int i = 0; i < deletegates.Length; i++)
        {
            //Remove all event
            onButtonPressed -= deletegates[i] as buttonPressed;
        }
    }
```

**2**.I don't know what you are doing but you may not need `Event Manager`. Just subscribe and un-subscribe in the `OnDisable` function. You can get event manager [here](http://www.bendangelo.me/unity3d/2014/12/24/unity3d-event-manager.html) if you still need it.

Comment: After writing my question I tried the OnDisable() way and it works but I was waiting for some answers because this solution seemed not very elegant to me. Thanks

Comment: Doing it in the OnDisable() function is the right way to go. It is guaranteed to work each time. You can use the clear all event method or  make your own Event Manager if you want.
See how Unity handles event here https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/events